# Issue in Creating Foundation Project

Tags: zurb-foundation

Trying to create a new foundation project using the steps

1. `foundation new project_name --libsass`

but not able to create and run , got this issue when i try to run the code, see the screenshot [image]

2.When I try to run `grunt` after that got this issue

[image]

Please help me in this. Thanks in advance for any help.